# Чем отличается preventDefault() от stopPropagation()?

Tags: gwt, java

Я использую оба метода, когда хочу закончить обработку события. Примерно как метод `comsume()` в Swing. И всегда ставлю вызовы этих методов вместе. Есть ли разница между
[`preventDefault()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/DomEvent.html#preventDefault()) и [`stopPropagation()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/DomEvent.html#stopPropagation())?

В документации сказано, что

> `stopPropagation`
>
> Останавливает распространение базового нативного события.
>
> `preventDefault`
>
> Предотвращает действие по умолчанию базового нативного события.

Как-то так. Но ясности это не вносит.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

preventDefault запрещает стандартное поведение элемента. Например, клик на кнопку сабмита производит отправку формы, preventDeafult это прекратит. Нажатие на ссылку перенаправляет на другую страницу $('a').preventDefault(); запретит это действе. Ссылка станет просто активной подчеркнутой областью.
stopPropagation запрещает передачу события от ребенка к родителю, то есть, если мы кликнули по вложенному диву, его родитель "не почувствует" этого нажатия.

Идеи примеров использования.
preventDefault: Тут все просто. Аяксовые ссылки.
stopPropagation: например, кнопки поверх картинки. Если кликаем по картинке, включается следующая, если по кнопкам - какое-то другое действие, скажем, лупа.

P.S. кликами все не ограничивается ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ну про `stopPropagation` ни чего сказать не могу, а про `preventDefault` этот метод не дает сработать базовым функциям, например хочешь ты на какую нибудь ссылку повесить обработчик вот тогда тебе это и надо ставить что б комп не перешол по сслыку а выполнил твой код. Как то так.